# Why $\int_\gamma\frac{ f(z)}{z-a}dz$ is not well defined when $a\in \gamma $.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma $ a closed curve. Why $\int_\gamma\frac{ f(z)}{z-a}dz$ is not well defined when $a\in \gamma $ ?

Comment: if $f(a) \ne 0$ it is obvious, since $\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz = \int_a^b \frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-a} \gamma'(t) dt$ for any $C^1$ parametrization of the contour

Comment: once this is clear, you can make sense to it when $a \in \gamma$ with the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), and you get $p.v.  \ \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a} dz = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2}(\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a+\epsilon} dz+\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a-\epsilon} dz)$ (where the limit has to be non tangential to $\gamma'(a)$)

Comment: This [discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/479237/21783) may be of interest.

Comment: Why would you think it's well defined? The integrand has a bad blow up singularity.

Comment: @user1952009 why does that integral diverge for any extension of $\frac{f(\gamma(t))}{\gamma(t)-a}\gamma'(t)$ to an interval that includes $a$?

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Let call $\Gamma$ the curve in pink (on the left) and $\tilde \Gamma$ the curve in blue (on the right).
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\mathrm d z=2\pi i \text{Res}_{z=a}(f),$$
whereas $$\int_{\tilde \Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\mathrm d z=0.$$

Therefore, excepted in the case where $\text{Res}_{z=a}(f)=0$, letting $\varepsilon\to 0$, you will have an undefined result.

Comment: There's no reason to think $f$ is analytic anywhere, so I'm not sure what Res(f) is supposed to mean.

Comment: @zhw. the complex-analysis tag, and the notation used for the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: @user1952009  Sure it's complex analysis, but a contour integral is defined in general for any $f$ continuous on the range of the contour.

Comment: @zhw in the context it is clear $f$ is analytic around $\gamma$. 'complex-analysis' : The theory of functions of one complex variable with an emphasis on the theory of complex analytic (or holomorphic) functions of one complex variable.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to consider the function value of the integrand at every point of $\gamma$, and the integrand is just not defined on the whole of $\gamma$. To illustrate my point, let $\eta:[c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a parametrization of $\gamma$, then
$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \text{dz} = \int_c^d \frac{f(\eta(t))}{\eta(t)-a}\eta'(t) \text{dt}.$$ 
But the function in the integrand is not well-defined, because there is some $\alpha \in [c,d]$ such that $\eta(\alpha)=a$, and then you divide by zero.

Comment: Depending on your definition of integral, you may not actually need to know the integrand is defined at _every_ point.  But the integrand certainly has the potential to be unbounded (even ignoring sets of measure $0$), and so it is not obvious that the integral has to exist.

Comment: @M.Van if $z = \eta(t)$ then $dz = \eta'(t) dt$

Comment: @user1952009 you are right. I edited it, it doesn't change the idea of the explanation fortunately.

Comment: the idea is that it diverges as $\int_{-b}^b \frac{dx}{x}$ : $\eta(t) - a \sim (t-a)\eta'(a)$ so it is like $\int_{-b}^{b} \frac{f(a)}{t-a}dt$

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, you could make sense of that integral if you know you can continuously extend $g(z):=\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$, or if 'giving' $g$ any value at $a$ results in a function that is integrable over $\gamma$ (since changing the value of a function at one point does not change the value and existence of the integral).

Comment: @user1952009 it does not have to diverge, consider the case $f(z)=z-a$.

Comment: that's why my comment above : if $f(a) \ne 0$ (and $f(z)$ is analytic)...

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know if I follow your reasoning, could you elaborate?

Comment: in the context it was clear $f$ is analytic around $\gamma$. furthermore we can choose $\eta'(a) = 1$, so that $\frac{f(\eta(t))}{\eta(t)-a} \eta'(t) \sim \frac{f(a)}{t-a}$ around $a$, not integrable whenever $f(a) \ne 0$

Comment: Don't you only need continuity for this? Also what do you mean exactly by $\sim$? (I understand the intuition though)